# Rails collection_select set value for include_blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Help me please to solve problem with collection_select.
When I use:

```
collection_select(:service, :carmake_id, Carmake.all, :id, :name, include_blank: 'Any')
```

HTML is:

```
<select id="service_carmake_id" name="service[carmake_id]">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="12">Audi</option>
  <option value="16">Porsche</option>
  <option value="17">VW</option>
</select>
```

But I need value="0" for "Any" option.
Is it possible?

Update:

```
select(:service, :carmake_id, [['Any', 0]] + Carmake.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id]})
```

helped me, but there is railsway? Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: What if you pass `[0, 'Any']`?

Comment: But I think it makes no sense. Looks like you're asking for DEFAULT value not blank. Blank by definition is a value which will fail `presence` check

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel what you told is correct, But Does he really able to find any record with id '0'. Because definitely this select is a part of some form. So Whats the point of entering '0' in any id carmake_id field.

Comment: I don't understand above comment?

Comment: @RailsGuy of course it makes no sense, that's why I added second comment.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, [0, 'Any'] generates <option value=""></option>. I need carmake_id '0' in db request, to reduce code and don't write conditions with NULL.

Comment: iAnton - did you read my second comment?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, sure. I have condition like: Service.select([:name]).where('(carmake_id = ?) , carmake'), and carmake is integer, but sometimes it's NULL, and for this case I have to add another condition like 'carmaker_id is NULL' and I guess use 0 is simpler.

Comment: @iAnton and do you ever try to select all services with null carmake_id?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, yeah, my condtion is Service.select([:name]).where('(carmake_id = ?) AND (carmodel_id = ?) AND (carconfiguration_id = ?) AND (lower(name) LIKE lower(?))', carmake, carmodel, carconfiguration, "%#{params[:name]}%"). And I show services for different make, model and configuration, if ids = 0, service useful for any car.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might work:

```
options = Carmake.all.unshift Carmake.new(id: 0, name: 'Any')
collection_select(:service, :carmake_id, options, :id, :name, include_blank: 'Any')
```

Although I did not test saving/updating in action.